# setInterval () is not working after using onclick clearInterval ()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, setinterval

Please help me when I am using the setInterval () function then suddenly while using clearInterval (),  everything works fine.

But Automatic working li elements with class automatically stopped working.

anybody have any solution or idea how to fix this error,  **after using the previous and next button how to run setInterval() again**

Any kind of help is
Highly appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/9nu5x3z4/

here is code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.mydivs div:first').addClass('active');
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // Remove .active class from the active li, select next li sibling.
  divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).addClass('active');
  }, 2000);

    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
 
    $("#next").click(function (e) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
        divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).addClass('active'); 
       
    });
    
    $("#prev").click(function (e) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
        divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).addClass('active');
       
    });
});
```

```css
.mydivs {
   
    border:5px solid #ccf;
}

.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydivs">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
<div class="mydivs-bt">
<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably stops working because you are not restarting `setInterval` after canceling it on **prev**/**next** click.

```js
    var intervalId;
    function startInterval() {
      intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
            now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
            divs.eq(now).addClass('active');
      }, 2000);
    }
    startInterval();

    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
 
    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).addClass('active'); 
        startInterval();
    });
    
    $("#prev").click(function (e) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
        divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).addClass('active');
        startInterval();
    });
```

```css
.mydivs {
   
    border:5px solid #ccf;
}

.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydivs">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
<div class="mydivs-bt">
<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I Press Prev Button simultaneously then this ticker crashed

means multiple .active classes automatically  added into <div>DIV #1</div> Kindly help

I don;t why this error occur kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You are not restarting your interval. Make sure to reassign `intervalId` with a new interval after navigating from prev/next.

I also took the liberty of simplifying some of your logic. There was a lot of redundant code. Hopefully this code will assist you in understanding.

**Edit:** I threw in some [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to improve the CSS.

```js
var now = 0; // currently shown div
var intervalId;
var $divs = $('.mydivs > div');

function stop() {
  if (intervalId != null) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  }
}

function start() {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    advance(1);
  }, 2000);
}

function restart() {
  stop();
  start();
}

function addMod(x, n, m) {
  return (x + n + m) % m;
}

// Remove .active class from the active li, select next li sibling.
function advance(dir) {
  $divs.eq(now).removeClass('active');
  now = addMod(now, dir, $divs.length);
  $divs.eq(now).addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $divs.first().addClass('active');
  start();

  $("#next").click(function(e) {
    stop();
    advance(1);
    start();
  });

  $("#prev").click(function(e) {
    stop();
    advance(-1);
    start();
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mydivs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.mydivs > div {
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #666;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.25em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.mydivs > div.active {
  color: #F00;
  border: thin dashed #F00;
}

.mydivs-bt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0.25em;
}

.mydivs-bt > div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: thin solid #666;
  background: #444;
}

.mydivs-bt > div:hover {
  background: #666;
  border-color: thin solid #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydivs">
  <div>DIV #1</div>
  <div>DIV #2</div>
  <div>DIV #3</div>
  <div>DIV #4</div>
</div>
<div class="mydivs-bt">
  <div id="prev">Prev</div>
  <div id="next">Next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I Press Prev Button simultaneously then this ticker crashed

means multiple .active classes automatically added into <div>DIV #1</div> Kindly help